# To check number alphabets in a string

Tags: c

When I execute this program k value should be like 0,1,2,3 but instead its showing some random values for k.
After executing for loop the value of 'i' is not changing.If the initial value of 'i' is 0. After executing for loop for 100 times the value of 'i' is still 0.

input  -asd

output -12345678910111213

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i,k=0;
    char array[100];
    scanf("%s",&array);

    for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]>='a'&&array[i]<='z')
        {
            k=k+1;
            printf("%d",k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the reference symbol from array

Comment: This does not really matter, but you should declare `i` inside the loop like that `for (int i = 0; .....)`

Comment: You should indent your code.

Comment: *showing some random values* they are not random values - It is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13. Keeping this in mind you should be able to figure what is going wrong

Comment: Print a newline after important data: `printf("%d\n", k);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use a for-loop going to 99. You only want to continue to the end of the input string, i.e. until you find the zero-termination.
2. Never do `scanf("%s", array);` as there is no limit on the length of the input. The user can overflow the array by typing a string longer than 100.

For problem 1) you can use a `while` and for problem 2) use `fgets` as it allows you to specify a maximum number of characters

Then your code could look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,k=0;
    char array[100];
    fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin);
    while(array[i])
    {
        if(array[i]>='a' && array[i]<='z')
        {
            k=k+1;
            printf("%d",k);
        }
        i = i +1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following could work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    int i,k=0;
    char array[100];

    scanf("%s", array);
    for(i=0;array[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if(array[i]>='a'&&array[i]<='z')
        {
            k=k+1;
            printf("%d",k);
        }
    }

   return 0; 
}
```